# Which of these lenses allows a greater amount of light through at f/1.4: Canon 35mm f/1.4 or Sigma 35mm f/1.4?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, canon, wide-angle, sigma

I'm looking for a wide aperture wide angle lens to use with my 5D III body. I'm planning to use this lens for reportage shots in low light conditions.

After doing some research, I'm trying to decide between Canon 35mm f/1.4 and Sigma 35mm f/1.4.

If you trust the [tests](http://learningcameras.com/reviews/7-lenses/87-sigma-35mm-f14-vs-canon-35mm-f14), Sigma seems to perform better than Canon in the fair light.

Some time ago, I've tested Zeiss 100mm f/2 at f/2 vs Canon 50mm f/1.4 at f/1.4 in low light conditions, and I felt that the Zeiss actually performed better. I think this is because of the quality of the glass used in those lenses. That's why, despite that both lenses have f/1.4, I'm really worried if Sigma is going to be at least as good as Canon in low light.

Did anyone compare those those two lenses in low light conditions? Also, are there any other reasons (except no weather sealing on Sigma) why I shouldn't get the Sigma lens?

**UPDATE**
What I meant with better performance of Zeiss is the amount of light transmitted.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Canon EF 35mm f/1.4L USM isn't weather sealed, so that's no different from the Sigma.

Comment: well, this looks interesting: http://www.amazon.com/review/R90LRWO9H0HO8/ref=cm_cr_pr_viewpnt#R90LRWO9H0HO8 `On the copies I have, the sigma offers no increase in sharpness or image quality when compared to the canon, a substantial step or two down in terms of vignetting, and requires approximately 1/3 of a stop slower shutter speed to expose the photo equivalently to the canon.` Looks like a deal breaker for me ((

Comment: Vignetting is quite easily fixed in post though, and it looks like it's only an issue at f/1.4, and gone by f/2.0. Compare it to the Canon here: http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Lens-Vignetting-Test-Results.aspx?Lens=121&Camera=9&FLI=0&API=0&LensComp=829&CameraComp=453&FLIComp=0&APIComp=0

Comment: well, i'm going to be using it at f/1.4 a lot. no point in buying a f/1.4 lens to use it at f/2. And the deal breaker for me is that it appears to eat less light than the canon as I feared (this is extremely important to me)

Comment: it's a shame though. because according to this test: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151194592101767&set=pb.9329881766.-2207520000.1361101573&type=3&theater the bokeh on canon can get REALLY ugly (

Comment: When you say "performed" are you referring to image quality or AF speed and accuracy?

Comment: You can get different bokeh by attaching some glassless filter rings (you did save the rings when you broke the glass) or some hoods intended for less wide lens (e.g. try a hood for 50mm on the 35mm).  Maybe one of those things will give you an effect.  You will get some vignetting, too ... of course.

Comment: @MichaelClark Ziess doesn't have AF, otherwise we wouldn't have this discussion and I've already bought Zeiss 35mm f/1.4. What I meant is that Zeiss lens did let much more light through. Canon 85mm f/1.2 is definitely brighter than the Zeiss f/2 though

Comment: @Arsen: Yah, I missed that about the Zeiss. If you're defining *performance* as **actual light transmission** rather than **image sharpness** maybe you should edit the question to reflect this. I think most of the answers are assuming you are looking for the sharpest lens.

Comment: @MichaelClark title edited )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm in the process of choosing a 35mm myself, and I think I'm leaning towards the Sigma (need to look into how the Bokeh looks on both the Sigma and Canon).

If you look at [Roger's take](http://www.lensrentals.com/rent/canon/lenses/wide-angle/sigma-35mm-f1.4-dg-hsm-a1-for-canon) over at Lensrentals it's clear that they think the Sigma is the superior lens. [The Digital Picture](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Sigma-35mm-f-1.4-EX-DG-HSM-Lens-Review.aspx) also seems to have a liking for the Sigma, so does [dpreview.com](http://www.dpreview.com/lensreviews/sigma-35mm-f1-4-dg-hsm/5), it seems that most agree that the Sigma is superior. If you look at when they were released (2012 for the Sigma and 1998 for the Canon), I'm not too surprised that the Sigma is better.

You might want to consider the Canon EF 35mm f/2 IS USM Lens as an option if you're mainly concerned about shooting hand held in low light. You might benefit from the IS. According to The Digital Picture the image quality of the [35mm f/2 IS rivals that of the Canon 35mm f/1.4L](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-35mm-f-2-IS-USM-Lens-Review.aspx), which doesn't sound too unlikely, since the design is so much newer (2012). Of course the IS only helps if the subject isn't fast moving, but then 3-4 stops from the IS might be more useful than the difference in aperture.

Comment: I'm personally of an opinion that no amount of IS can compensate for reduced aperture in a lens. And the f/2 is a non-L lens, meaning that the quality of the image is going to suffer. Thanks, but no, thank you

Comment: Made an edit to add some info about the quality of the EF 35mm f/2 IS.

Comment: ) ok. what I'm deciding between is canon L and sigma lenses, and to me canon f/2 won't ever out-perform the canon L lens, so it's out of the equation. I simply don't think it's up to the task. I'm not considering sigma because it's cheaper, only because it _might_ be better

Comment: check this out: http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/post/50700998 some focus problems in bad light

Comment: Look like that was due to a bad copy, the original poster said as much. http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/post/50733155

Comment: also, what worries me is that I don't understand why Sigma is nearly twice as cheap as Canon. It's not Canon, that's $200 discount. Where are the other $300?

Comment: This is speculations, but an old design might be more expensive to produce. By using newer techniques and materials, you might be able to reduce the cost, but maintain (or increase) the quality.

Comment: hehe. as canon proved by producing plasticky version of 24-70 which costs twice as much )

Comment: That plasticky version is a LOT sharper too!

Comment: In my experience the "L" designation is as much about fit, finish, and durability as it is about image quality. Canon makes some very good non-L glass. The EF-S 17-55 f/2.8 has better optics than the EF 17-40 f/4L. Of course they also make some consumer grade junk.

As to IS, I find myself in many situations where my EF 24-70 f/2.8 stays in my bag and my EF 24-105 F/4 stays on my camera, especially if I'm moving a lot and shooting handheld. At comparable apertures and focal lengths, there isn't that much difference in sharpness, distortion or vignetting between the two.

Comment: When you say "perform" do you mean image quality or AF speed/accuracy?

Answer (score 6):

Lens performance is linear, the quality of the projected image at f/1.4 in good light is exactly the same as the quality of the projected image at f/1.4 in poor light. The sensor is what matters for low light performance.

Secondly you can't really compare a 50mm to a 100mm lens, you get very different images.

To answer your question, the Sigma is optically far superior to the Canon, which is 15 years old now I think. Canon will come out with a much better version this year, probably better even than the Sigma but will charge around $2000. If I were you I'd get the Sigma now.

Comment: `The oft rumored EF 35 f/1.4L II is being talked about again. We’re told an announcement for the new “L” prime will only happen once the new EF 24-70 f/2.8L II begun shipping in decent quantity.

That would put the announcement sometime in 2012 with availability probably being in early 2013. One patent for the optical forumla has been around for a while.` The rumor has come and gone many times already

Comment: @ArsenZahray it's by no means certain that Canon replace the 35 f/1.4L this year, but I think the release of the Sigma 35 f/1.4 is going to give Canon the hurry up.

Comment: well, it's about time, and for 50mm f/1.2 too.

Comment: Fast lenses like that can behave quite differently from another especially in low-light, brutal contrast scenarios - flare, astigmatism, coma. Even worse if deciding to accept severe overexposure of point light sources to favor darker parts: A flare that is 1% the brightness of the light source can become a huge, fully exposed ghost that way....

Answer (score 1):

On your behalf I've done some review reading and pixelpeeping of the 35mm choices.

If I were to choose and money was no issue, the only two I would consider is Sigma 35 1.4 or Canon 35 F/2 IS (not the non IS). I agree that IS is a marketing gimmick, except for telephotos, as it only helps with static scenes and the IQ is better keeping it off. So my evaluation applies to keeping IS off.

Those two lenses are the only ones that has nice bokeh rendition and sharpness. Canon f/2 IS wins on bokeh, and Sigma wins on sharpness. Also, if you need faster than F/2 then Sigma 35mm 1.4 is the only option.

So I think it is just a matter of "add to cart" on the Sigma page.

Pixelpeep here:

http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/ISO-12233-Sample-Crops.aspx?Lens=829&Camera=453&Sample=0&FLI=0&API=2&LensComp=121&CameraComp=0&FLIComp=0&APIComp=0

Compare bokeh here:

http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Sigma-35mm-f-1.4-EX-DG-HSM-Lens-Review.aspx

Comment: I used to also feel there was no need for IS at less than about 70mm focal length. Long before IS existed (at least on 35mm camera lenses) I could handhold and beat the 1/focal length rule by 2-3 stops with enough consistency to do it back when you didn't see any results until the film was processed. I'm twice as old now as I was then. Since buying the EF 24-105mm f/4L IS mostly for the reach as a walkaround lens I'm discovering IS can be very useful at shorter focal lengths at times when a tripod isn't practical or even possible. On the other hand, f/1.4 is a full stop faster than f/2.

Comment: but in a dynamic situation it does more harm, and only going for a large front glass help with that :)

Comment: Not every scene is dynamic, is it? f/2 and a Tv of 1/8 allows twice as much light to reach the sensor as f/1.4 and Tv of 1/30 sec. In general when we are talking about low light we are not concerned with exposing too far to the right, so the more light we can allow to fall on the sensor, the higher the quality of the image will be. *Reportage shots* may include static subjects as well as dynamic ones. For instance the mangled remains of a vehicle involved in an accident are static. Even with people in the scene they may be *static enough* for the slower Tv.

Comment: I agree that there are times when only a large objective lens will do. But don't throw the baby out with the bath water. Even at wider focal lengths IS is useful in many situations. Many of the world's most famous news photos were taken, due to the constraints of the technology of the time, at much slower Tvs than we like to use now. In many cases IS is just the modern equivalent of the photojournalist's tripod from a century ago.

Answer (score 0):

DigitalRev did a comparison of Canon, Nikon, and Sigma 35mm f/1.4 lenses that you may find helpful:

[Battle of the Bokeh - Canon, Nikon Sigma 35mm f/1.4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=edJStBgM6GQ)

It doesn't address low light specifically, but as Matt Grum points out above, lens performance doesn't depend on the amount of light.

Comment: `ens performance doesn't depend on the amount of light` well, that's something new to me )

Comment: @Arsen: If you're defining *performance* as actual **light transmission** rather than **image sharpness** maybe you should edit the question to reflect this. I think most of the answers are assuming you are looking for the *sharpest* lens.

Comment: in what way does light affect lens performance? I thought the lens did the same thing to one single photon as it would billions of photons? Maybe the heat from the light will slightly bend the glass so it changes the performance?

Comment: @MichaelNielsen: Arsen seems to be referring to **overall light transmission rather than sharpness** when he uses the word *performance*. No lens is *exactly* the indicated aperture at any given setting. His original question is in no way clear at this point, however.

Comment: The lens still performs the same with 1 photon and billions, letting through p % ;P

Comment: Yes, but the question *should* be, "Which of these lenses allows a greater amount of light through at f/1.4."

Comment: @MichaelClark I expect that's what the OP meant, but the point is that the lens will transmit the same percentage of light at f/1.4 in low light as it does at f/1.4 in bright light. A given lens may be faster or slower than other similar lenses, but it will be faster or slower than the others by the same amount regardless of the amount of light.

Comment: Yes, it is true that each lens will transmit the same % of light regardless of the amount of light. **When comparing these two lenses the *actual aperture* for each when set to f/1.4 is likely *much more disparate* than the % of light transmitted** by the elements of each lens along the center axis as measured on an optical test bench. Most lenses have more accurate effective apertures in the middle of their range than at the extreme, especially on the wide end where manufacturers tend to fudge in the direction that makes them look better. In this context, amount of light *does* matter.

Comment: In other words, *a given lens will probably be faster or slower than the other similar lenses by a greater amount at the widest aperture than at middle apertures.*

Comment: @MichaelClark The widest aperture has little to do with the available light. Yes, you're more likely to use the widest aperture when there's little light around, and that's why we all understand intuitively what the OP is talking about, but the question is stated incorrectly. You can shoot at f/22 in low light and you can shoot at f/1.4 in bright light; the behavior of the lens may change with aperture, but it's not related to the available light.